# Why does scrheadings + tgschola triggers a font shape warning?

Tags: fonts, koma-script, warnings

This code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tgschola}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

gives this warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/qcs/m/sl' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/qcs/m/it' tried instead on input line 11.
```

Apparently some text was changed from slanted to italic, but there's no output of slanted or itcalic text in the document at all. There's only a roman "a". The warning is also only triggered if theres *something* (at least one letter) in the document (regular text or math), it does not trigger in an empty document.

**Why is a font warning written to the log when no text is affected at all?**

Is this a bug of `scrpage2`?

Comment: Yes, there is such text in eventual headings.

Comment: The headings in the default `scrheadings` style *are* typeset in slanted shape. So the `\fontshape{sl}\selectfont` instruction is (implicitly) issued and this causes LaTeX to look for the font in the `.fd` file; this ends in the warning, as explained in my other answer to your similar question.

Comment: @egreg So the warning is thrown even if there's no heading printed, because it's enough that the package *could maybe* request a specific font shape? Did I get this right?

Comment: That font shape *is* requested because the heading *is* printed even if it's empty: TeX must be ready to print something, so it sets the current font before finding characters to typeset.

Comment: @egreg Ah, now I got it. Didn't know that empty headings get printed, I thought it gets skipped. If you write your comment as an answer I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default `scrheadings` style uses slanted shape, so LaTeX sees the request for this font. Since the default font family is `qcs` and the encoding is `T1`, something equivalent to

```
\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{qcs}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{sl}\selectfont
```

is issued. Actually probably only `\slshape` is found in the code, but this is sufficient.

It's important to know that TeX first sets the current font before starting to typeset characters. The fact that the headings are empty doesn't matter.

You get the same message from the simple file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fontfamily{qcs}\fontshape{sl}\selectfont
\stop
```

because the request for a font makes TeX read the file `t1qcs.fd` and search for `T1/qcs/m/sl` finding the (non silent) substitution rule.